# Sum of count where values are less than row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas to come up with new column that will search through the entire column with values [1-100] and will count the values where it's less than the current row.

See [df] example below:

```
[A][NewCol]
 1 0
 3 2
 2 1
 5 4
 8 5
 3 2
```

Essentially, for each row I need to look at the entire Column A, and count how many values are less than the current row. So for Value **5**, there are ***4*** values that are less (<) than 5 (1,2,3,3).

What would be the easiest way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: seems like what you are looking for is your custom version of the rank(A) - checkout https://pandas.pydata.org/pandasdocs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html to see if you can achieve the result from the rank function as that would be the cleanest implementation here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it like this, use `rank` with `method='min'`:

```
df['NewCol'] = (df['A'].rank(method='min') - 1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   A  NewCol
0  1       0
1  3       2
2  2       1
3  5       4
4  8       5
5  3       2
```

Comment: I think the output need little bit adjust .

Comment: @Wen-Ben Thanks.

Comment: @Wen-Ben LOL  I knew this could be done with rank. I had to stumble through all of the rank methods. :)

Comment: Looks better now :-)

Comment: Thank you! I was originally thinking of using rank but I dint know you could use the min method and subtract 1. Genius!

Answer (score 7):

I am using `numpy` broadcast

```
s=df.A.values
(s[:,None]>s).sum(1)
Out[649]: array([0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2])

#df['NewCol']=(s[:,None]>s).sum(1)
```

---

timing

```
df=pd.concat([df]*1000)

%%timeit
s=df.A.values
(s[:,None]>s).sum(1)
10 loops, best of 3: 83.7 ms per loop
%timeit (df['A'].rank(method='min') - 1).astype(int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 479 µs per loop
```

Comment: Is possible add timings? I guess rank should be faster, but not 100% sure in large data.

Comment: @jezrael I feel like the same :-)

Comment: Is possible add timings?

Comment: Thank you, only not sure what data re used for timeit?

Comment: @jezrael added :-)

Comment: @Wen-Ben - Thank you, interesting pandas beat numpy :)

Comment: @jezrael ummm feel like rank is using some thing like binary search to get the result , rather that o(n,n)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
A = [Your numbers]
less_than = []
    for element in A:
        counter = 0
        for number in A:
            if number < element:
                counter += 1
        less_than.append(counter)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,3,2,5,8,3]})

df['NewCol'] = 0
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[idx, 'NewCol'] = (df.loc[:, 'A'] < row.A).sum()

print(df)
```

```
   A  NewCol
0  1       0
1  3       2
2  2       1
3  5       4
4  8       5
5  3       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is sort and reset index:

```
m=df.A.sort_values().reset_index(drop=True).reset_index()
m.columns=['new','A']
print(m)

   new  A
0    0  1
1    1  2
2    2  3
3    3  3
4    4  5
5    5  8
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify if speed or memory usage was important (or if you had a very large dataset).  The "easiest" way to do it is straightfoward: calculate how many are less then i for each entry in the column and collect those into a new column:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,3,2,5,8,3]})
col=df['A']
df['new_col']=[ sum(col<i) for i in col ]

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   A  new_col
0  1        0
1  3        2
2  2        1
3  5        4
4  8        5
5  3        2
```

There might be more efficient ways to do this on large datasets, such as sorting your column first.